# Is there such thing as: Phone <=> Ethernet Converter/Adapter

Tags: networking, phone

Consider two homes, one in San Diego and one in New York. Both have residential-grade ISPs  and SonicWall SOHO routers. The SOHO routers connect to one another via site-to-site VPN so LAN members in San Diego (192.168.1.0/24) and New York (192.168.2.0/24) can communicate freely. The connection is highly reliable.

The cable modem in San Diego, in addition to supplying my Internet connection there, has a separate phone port. A landline phone is plugged into it. It's a highly reliable phone connection.

Question: Is there a device that would allow me to relay the phone signal in San Diego to a land line phone in New York? The connection would look like this:

SD-CableModem ==(phone cord)==> SD-Device@(192.168.1.50) ==(ethernet)==> [cloud/vpn] ==(ethernet)==> NY-Device@(192.168.2.50) ==(phone cord)==> NY-LandLinePhone

The device wouldn't really do too much other than convert the phone signal to a stream of bytes, forward those bytes over the VPN to an identical device in the other city, convert the bytes back to a phone signal and pass it on to the phone. When picking up the phone in New York, I'd be hear a San Diego dial tone. Calls originating from that New York phone would show my San Diego caller ID.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do requires a VoIP setup. I have seen something similar being done but it was on another scale (on a huge network across different countries and a call to that number would ring a few hundred phones). An easy solution would be 'porting' your number to a VoIP software or service of your choosing (MagicJack for example allow you to 'port' your landline number and receive/place calls on a app on your mobile, it would work much like Skype or Viber but using the number you transfer to it...).
Notice that this solution will involve a 3rd part on your communication. To avoid* this you must create your own VoIP setup (higher costs in time and money). For example the NY-Device@(192.168.2.50) would be: MAIN ROUTER=>SIP=>Router‑Modular‑VoIP Adapter=>T1=>Voice Router=>NY-PHONE (i am assuming a ASA connected to your main Router, a possible IPbrick and ofcourse a Power Over the Ethernet Switch and IP-phones... this is just the NY part, something similar have to be done to receive the landline and make it available on the VPN. Using a virtual setup using emulators, can reduce costs but i have no more information about this.
*you are still sharing your communication with your ISP, i am not suggesting they are listening, i am just stating the fact that your data is flowing through them.

Comment: Thanks, friend. This is good info. I was hoping this is something that could be done with a $30 adapter device on each end but it looks like it's far more complicated than that. Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Magicjack cost about that per year, and there is a few devices like Voice Bridge that do basically that but to your mobile not another land-line phone.